# How to reference a paper submitted for publication using the following format

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to figure out how to reference a paper that has been submitted for publication using the following required format (consider this example):

> [1] Author 1, Author 2, and Author 3, "Proof of Pythagoras's theorem", submitted for publication to *Conference in Pure Mathematics* May 2022

How can we create a bibtex entry in this format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Is it crucial that the publication's title be surrounded by quotation marks?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!, the style I am using is ```abbrv```. Moreover, it is curcial for the publication title to have these quotation mark. @Mico

Comment: If it's crucial to encase the title in quotation marks, you are out of luck with the `abbrv` bib style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what follows, I will assume that it's not crucial for the publication's title to be surrounded by quotation marks.

If this assumption is valid, you could employ the `natbib` citation package with the option `numbers`, load the `abbrvnat` bib style, and choose the `@misc` entry type the entry in question. Alternatively, I suppose you could employ the `cite` citation management package and the `abbrv` bib style.

```
@misc{aaa:2022,
  author = {Author~1 and Author~2 and Author~3},
  title  = {Proof of the {Pythagorean} theorem},
  note   = {Submitted for publication to \emph{Conference 
            in Pure Mathematics} May 2022}
}
```

This setup should work with any bib style that can create numeric-style citation call-outs, and not just the `abbrvnat` and `abbrv` bib styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solves 99% of the question except that I wasn't aware that inserting quotation marks would be challenging in bibtex but then again bibtex is a pain in the...

Comment: @SofiaYaseveya - It's not challenging if you use a suitable bib style. Unfortunately, `abbrv` is not one of them. I guess you could use a kludge such as `title  = {``{Proof} of the {Pythagorean} theorem''},` i.e., hard-code the quotation marks. I wouldn't do it, though.